# Mounting Azure drive on outside server

Tags: azure-storage

I am asking here if any one has had success mounting a azure file storage on a ubuntu server that is not a part of Azure.

I created an Azure storage account and mounted that as a folder on my Ubuntu sever which is hosted in Azure but I also want to mount the same on another ubuntu server which is not a part of the Azure network.

Any ideas how this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Azure storage only allows mounting to Azure VMs in the same region as the storage account. You can access files via the REST interface from anywhere